# Something like DirectStorage API (Optimized NVMe Access) for C# applications without DirectX

Tags: c#, performance

Microsoft released the DirectStorage API for DirectX 12 on Windows 10 and Windows 11.

**Is there a way to get the fast (NVMe optimized) disk I/O like DirectStorage for C# applications that are not games and not targeting DirectX 12?**

"DirectStorage is a feature intended to allow games to make full use of high-speed storage (such as NVMe SSDs) that can can deliver multiple gigabytes a second of small (eg 64kb) data reads with minimal CPU overhead."

See: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectStorage